# iframe not being displayed in a widget

Tags: widgets, iframe

I'm trying to write my first widget, so i'm not that expert with the code.
I have the following code in my `functions.php` but the iframe is not being displayed:

```
class account_internet extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::WP_Widget( 'account_internet', 'Account internet', array('description' => 'Widget description goes here'));
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {

        $defaults = array( 
            'title' => 'Creazione account internet'
        );

        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">
                Title:
            </label>
            <input class="widefat" type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />

        </p>


        <?php
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        extract( $args );

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        ?>
            <iframe height="300px" width="150px" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );

        return $instance;
    }                     
}

function account_internet_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'account_internet' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'account_internet_register_widgets' );
```

Is there something that I miss?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong.  Can you see/configure your widget in wp-admin, especially the title from your form()?

Comment: FYI, I added your code to my WP instance and it worked for me!

Comment: Yes for the title. I'm testing it on WAMP server...could this be the problem? Cause i only get a 300x150px white space under widget's title...

Comment: UPDATE: if i set the URL without the http:// i get
"Not Found

The requested URL /test/www.yahoo.com was not found on this server."

seems to be a wamp problem then?